# Selenium and Chromedriver won't talk to each other when started from command-line

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

For our integration tests, we're using selenium and different (versions of) drivers for Chrome, Firefox and IE. There is no UI (or X for that matter) on our build-server, i.e. headless. We're using Xvfb for the virtual screen (framebuffer).

There is no error if I run it on my local machine which has X (a UI).

I have an easy enough test-class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9515"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.quit();
    }
```

I then start the chromedriver on port 9515. The exception I'm getting is this:

```
abc@xyz:~/test$ java -cp $CLASSPATH Test

(google-chrome:22323): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
[0124/165659:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending sends
chrome/test/automation/proxy_launcher.cc:107: Failure
Value of: app_launched
  Actual: 5
Expected: AUTOMATION_SUCCESS
Which is: 0
Error while awaiting automation ping from browser process
[0124/165659:ERROR:automation_proxy.cc(319)] Channel error in AutomationProxy.
[0124/165659:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending sends
[0124/165659:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending sends
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary at: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information); duration or timeout: 223 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.9.0', revision: '14289', time: '2011-10-20 23:22:17'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-28-server', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:417)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:76)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:84)
    at Test.main(Test.java:63)
```

I have been googling extensively and tried many different approaches. As I've been trying to solve this for over 2 days, I might be overlooking a small detail.

I'm using:

```
$ uname -a
Linux bryant 2.6.32-28-server #55-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 10 23:57:16 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

google-chrome-stable 24.0.1312.56-r177594
chromedriver_linux64_23.0.1240.0, chromedriver_linux64_26.0.1383.0

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Are you sure it's even possible?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov: pretty sure it's possible as we had a running example of this setup on our old build machine. Still not quite sure what I'm missing...